# C++ deleting 2 dimensional pointer vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I've got a valgrind memory leak in C++.
I created a two dimensional vector pointer of my class Coordinate in my Main function and filled it with some random values:

```
vector< vector<Coordinate*> > parent_vector_coords;
parent_vector_coords.push_back(calculateCannonCoordinates(bow_x, bow_y,
    stern_x, stern_y, game, 2);
```

Now I need to delete the pointers. One approach was this:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < parent_vector_coords.size(); i++)
{
  for(unsigned int index = 0; index < parent_vector_coords[i].size(); index++)
  {
    delete parent_vector_coords[i][index];
  }
}
```

**EDIT** calculateCannonCoordinates:

```
vector<Coordinate*> calculateCannonCoordinates(int bow_x, int bow_y, 
    int stern_x, int stern_y, Game& game, int value)
  {
    vector<Coordinate*> coords;

    if(bow_x == stern_x)
    {
      if(bow_y < stern_y)
      {
        for(int index = bow_y; index <= stern_y; index++)
        {
          coords.push_back(new Coordinate(index, bow_x));
          game.getBoard()->getField()[index][bow_x].setValue(value);
        }
      }
      else if(bow_y > stern_y)
      {
        for(int index = bow_y; index >= stern_y; index--)
        {
          coords.push_back(new Coordinate(index, bow_x));
          game.getBoard()->getField()[index][bow_x].setValue(value);
        }
      }
    }
    else if(bow_y == stern_y)
    {
      if(bow_x < stern_x)
      {
        for(int index = bow_x; index <= stern_x; index++)
        {
          coords.push_back(new Coordinate(bow_y, index));
          game.getBoard()->getField()[bow_y][index].setValue(value);
        }
      }
      else if(bow_x > stern_x)
      {
        for(int index = bow_x; index >= stern_x; index--)
        {
          coords.push_back(new Coordinate(bow_y, index));
          game.getBoard()->getField()[bow_y][index].setValue(value);
        }
      }
    }

    return coords;
  }
```

But I still get a memory leak caused by the vector. Does somebody know the right way to delete the pointers?

Comment: Use smart pointers instead

Comment: Every time I see vector<vector< >> modelling a matrix, I die a little inside. Use a proper matrix class.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers in your vector?

Comment: can you give the signature for `calculateCannonCoordinates` and an exerpt from it that illustrates how it allocates memory?

Comment: Maybe ignore the "use smart pointers"/"use unique pointers" comments. Those are important things to ask yourself, but don't help you understand your current problem. The sample code you've posted is not leaking any Coordinates, you are properly deleting everything. Are you sure the vector itself is not leaking? Do you call new vector< vector<Coordinate*> >() at any point?

Comment: @taocp that's a good point but in this case might it be more sensible to simply store the coordinates by value? I.e. `vector< vector<Coordinate> >`.

Comment: @TooTone Yeah, you are right. I was thinking that OP needs to use pointer for some reason.

Comment: It's unclear why you have vector of vector of pointers to (presumably arrays of) coordinates, and how those coordinates are allocated. Please include the code for allocation of parent_vector_coords[i][index].

Comment: @taocp The problem I got is that we are a little restricted by the libraries we can use for the university exercise. I don't event think we talked about that in out lectures.

Comment: @Dan O No i'm not doing that. Where would i have to call that? On declaration?

Comment: How is the `calculateCannonCoordinates` implemented?

Comment: Just added calculateCannonCoordinates

Comment: Just to follow-up on my previous interaction with @taocp, I suggest you  use `vector< vector<Coordinate> >` and get rid of the `new`s and `delete`s altogether (this is probably a better approach anyway). Then see if your memory leaks go away. If they don't, then the memory leaks are coming from elsewhere in your implementation that you haven't shown us.

Comment: I think we'd need to see the code that calls calculateCannonCoordinates, it's somewhat likely that you're creating a copy of this vector and failing to call your function that cleans up the coordinates in side the nested vector.

Comment: @PatrickGruber if you're not dynamically allocating the vector, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys. I just checked and the line I am getting the error is the line, where I am actually using the vector: `makeBoatComponents("longboat", parent_vector_coords[0])`. I know it has  something to do with the vector, because both parameters are on different lines. The error is on the line I use the vetor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are still people viewing this question, I decided to give the answer.

It seemed like there was another Pointer Object in Coordinate, instantiated automatically (forgot about that at the time). I did not delete that Pointer before freeing the Coordinate. That's what caused the Valgrind Memory Leak Error.

Everybody who has a similar problem should consider the advises given in the comment section (Smart Pointers, etc.)